# How to access attributes in the xml with powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell

I am new to powershell and I would like to get the value of "isDeleted" attribute from the below xml string but not successful.

<ptdf:Personnel_Area xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf" peci:isDeleted="1">

I am posting this here hoping an expert can help me with it.

Thanks,
Bramha

I have done some google but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

The "isDeleted" attribute value can be checked using the where-object clause.

ex: $_.Position.Personnel_Area | Where-Object isDeleted -eq '1'

It worked for me.

Helpful Link: https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-parse-xml/